# How does one add an item to GTK's "recently used" file list from Python?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, gtk3

I'm trying to add to the "recently used" files list from Python 3 on Ubuntu.

I am able to successfully *read* the recently used file list like this:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk
recent_mgr = Gtk.RecentManager.get_default()
for item in recent_mgr.get_items():
    print(item.get_uri())
```

This prints out the same list of files I see when I look at "Recent" in Nautilus, or look at the "Recently Used" place in the file dialog of apps like GIMP.

However, when I tried adding an item like this (where `/home/laurence/foo/bar.txt` is an existing text file)...

```
recent_mgr.add_item('file:///home/laurence/foo/bar.txt')
```

...the file does not show up in the Recent section of Nautilus or in file dialogs. It doesn't even show up in the results returned by `get_items()`.

How can I add a file to GTK's recently used file list from Python?

Comment: @oldtechaa The list of recent files seen by Nautilus and the file dialog in other apps (including GIMP, Inkscape, and even Chrome) seem to be identical. Many apps default to filtering the list to their own file type, but if you change the filter to "All Files" you see exactly the same list that Nautilus shows, and that is displayed by the code in the question.

Comment: What does `add_item()` return?

Comment: @andlabs Calling `add_item()` returns `True`. (Actually, is seems to always return `True`, even if the URI I pass to it is nonexistant or complete nonsense. The only exception is if I pass it a non-`str`. Then it raises `TypeError`.)

Comment: Maybe not though seeing that `add_item()` returns true would suggest it is something else. Could it be picking up the wrong history file some how? If it returns true it suggests it succeeded in writing it somewhere.

Comment: The real question I have, which is unrelated to your code, is why `add_item()` doesn't use GError while every other method of GtkRecentManager does. I'll ask that later; maybe one of the GTK+ developers can guess what's going on...

Comment: @andlabs This is due to the use of asynchronous code to avoid `g_content_type_guess` to block the flow of the program I think, see my answer below.

Comment: @JacquesGaudin good to know then; thanks. And it seems `add_full()` is written in a way that even though it is synchronous, it cannot fail unless the input parameters are wrong. I'm not sure if this is smart, but oh well :/

Comment: @andlabs Not sure about the smartness of it either, especially when you realise that `g_content_type_guess` worst guess is the first mimetype in the system's mimetype list. Not a very smart guess !

Comment: Actually I should rephrase that: "it will hide failures of any of its underlying functions as it doesn't call the versions of those functions that could potentially report failures (if they even exist)"; I'd have to look at the GBookmarkFile API. Also, what would you suggest as a better worst-case, `application/octet-stream`?

Comment: @andlabs I may be a bit naive but I was thinking that there was a mimetype for unknown data file. The content type guess returns an uncertainty boolean which could be replaced with an unknown data mimetype linking to a hexadecimal editor maybe...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A `Gtk.RecentManager` needs to emit the `changed` signal for the update to be written in a private attribute of the C++ class. To use a `RecentManager` object in an application, you need to start the event loop by calling `Gtk.main`:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk

recent_mgr = Gtk.RecentManager.get_default()
uri = r'file:/path/to/my/file'
recent_mgr.add_item(uri)
Gtk.main()
```

If you don't call `Gtk.main()`, the `changed` signal is not emitted and nothing happens.

To answer @andlabs query, the reason why `RecentManager.add_item` returns a boolean is because the `g_file_query_info_async` function is called. The callback function `gtk_recent_manager_add_item_query_info` then gathers the mimetype, application name and command into a `GtkRecentData` struct and finally calls `gtk_recent_manager_add_full`. The source is [here](https://github.com/GNOME/gtk/blob/master/gtk/gtkrecentmanager.c).

If anything goes wrong, it is well after `add_item` has finished, so the method just returns `True` if the object it is called from is a `RecentManager` and if the uri is not `NULL`; and `False` otherwise.

The documentation is inaccurate in saying:

> Returns `TRUE` if the new item was successfully added to the recently used resources list

as returning `TRUE` only means that an asynchronous function was called to deal with the addition of a new item.

As suggested by Laurence Gonsalves, the following runs pseudo-synchronously:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, GObject

recent_mgr = Gtk.RecentManager.get_default()
uri = r'file:/path/to/my/file'
recent_mgr.add_item(uri)
GObject.idle_add(Gtk.main_quit)
Gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution (complet script) with timer for quit `GTK.main()` loop

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import gi

gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk, GLib
import sys
import os
import subprocess

recent_mgr = Gtk.RecentManager.get_default()

if len(sys.argv) <= 1:
    paths = (os.getcwd(),)
else:
    paths = sys.argv[1:]

for path in paths:
    if os.path.exists(path):
        if path[0] != "/":
            path = os.getcwd() + "/" + path
        subprocess.call(["touch", "-a", path])
        uri = r"file:" + path
        recent_mgr.add_item(uri)

GLib.timeout_add(22, Gtk.main_quit, None)
Gtk.main()
```